# Django REST Framework - Set request in serializer test?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I built a web app where the back-end is implemented using the Django REST Framework. Now I'm writing unit tests and I have come across a problem in testing my serializer methods. Here is one example of a serializer method I'm struggling with:

```
    def get_can_edit(self, obj):
      request = self.context.get('request')
      user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
      return user == obj.admin
```

When trying to call this from the test, first I declare an instance of the serializer:

```
self.serializer = ConferenceSerializer()
```

But now I need `self.serializer` to have the correct request when `get_can_edit` does `self.context.get('request')`. I've created a fake request with the correct information using [RequestFactory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/advanced/):

```
self.request1 = RequestFactory().get('./fake_path')
self.request1.user = self.user1
```

Now I am stuck because I am unsure how to add `request1` to `serializer` such that `self.context.get('request')` will return `request1`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to **pass `context` argument** to add `request1` to serializer's `context` while instantiating the serializer in your test.

From DRF docs on [including extra context:](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)

> You can provide arbitrary additional context by passing a `context`
>   argument when instantiating the serializer.

You need to do something like:

```
# pass context argument
self.serializer = ConferenceSerializer(context={'request': request1})
```

This will provide the desired `request1` object to your serializer in its `context`.