# Django REST Framework - Set request in serializer test for ApiClient

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I already read: [Django REST Framework - Set request in serializer test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771852/django-rest-framework-set-request-in-serializer-test). And it doesn't work for me! Because I'm using APIClient and not RequestFactory like him.

I built a web app where the back-end is implemented using the Django REST Framework. Now I'm writing unit tests and I have come across a problem in testing my serializer methods. Here is one example of a serializer method I'm struggling with:

```
def get_can_edit(self, obj):
  request = self.context['request']
  user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
  return user == obj.admin
```

When trying to call this from the test, first I declare an instance of the serializer:

But now I need self.serializer to have the correct request when get_can_edit does self.context.get('request'). I've created a fake request with the correct information using APIClient:

```
self.client = APIClient()
self.client.force_authenticate(user)
conference = a_fake_conference

res = self.client.get('conference:conference-detail'. args=[conference.id])
serializer = ConferenceSerializer(conference, context={WHAT_IS_REQUEST?}) 
# I'm using a dict as context but the request gave me an error: context={'request': { 'user': user }}

sert.assertEqual(res.data, serializer.data)
```

Now I am stuck because I am unsure how to add request1 to serializer such that `request = self.context['request']` will return

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`wsgi_request`** (source code-Django)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9cc743d0c82e019306d80eb8a83f86f8c6244610/django/test/client.py#L146) of **`APIClient`** to get the WSGI request object.

```
self.client = APIClient()
self.client.force_authenticate(user)
res = self.client.get('conference:conference-detail'. args=[conference.id]
# make sure to call the `get(...)` method before accessing `wsgi_request` attribute
request_object = res.wsgi_request
```

**Disclaimer:** Not sure whether this is a DRF way to get the `request` object.

Comment: It was awesome. BUT, based on the code: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/test.py#L280 wsgi_request doesnt exist. But, request exists. So, I tried with ```self.client.request()```, and it answered it's a dict, so finally I tried ```self.client.request``` and it returns something like: ```{'PATH_INFO': '/api/survey/', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SERVER_PORT': '80', 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/octet-stream'}``` It haven't solved my problem (because there is not user) but it's an awesome clue! Thanks!

Comment: I have added the `wsgi_request` reference (check updated answer)

Comment: My bad! Let me check!

Comment: You should access **`self.client.wsgi_request`** not `self.client.request`

Comment: I'd suggest you a little update: ```self.client.wsgi_request``` gives next error:  ```AttributeError: 'APIClient' object has no attribute 'wsgi_request'``` Why? Because it's an attribute of the used client after the get. So, in my code: it'd be like: ```res = self.client.get('conference:conference-detail'. args=[conference.id]) res.wsgi_request``` You can try! But It solved my problem, checking the ```res.wsgi_request``` instead of the client. Thanks, so much! If you change it I'd be my pleasure mark as accepted answer!

Comment: People like to say that the Django docs are good, but they're imbued with a marketing attitude reminscent of Microsoft. They like to pretend it's so simple so they say "just do this" and show an example but there's no actual _specification_ of the prototype, there's not even a list of parameters that it takes! And the example only shows a simple case. Dredging around online only turns up highly repetitive beginner scenarios that are often flawed and badly presented. The information that's needed is just not there. I'm going to look at the code ... no documentation to speak of for what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You're testing two things with each other here, so that's sort of part of the problem.  Typically, you'd use `self.client.get(...)` as an *integration test*, that is, a test that ensures that everything from request to response is working as expected.  For tests like these, you wouldn't use a serialiser, because then you're using your application code (your serialiser) to test itself.

If you're writing an integration test, you should be testing the raw response with something like:

```
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory

class MyUnitTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_the_whole_stack(self):
        response = self.client.get(
            "conference:conference-detail", args=[conference.id]
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(
            response.json()["some-key-you-expect"],
            "Some value you expect"
        )
```

Note that you also don't have to invoke APIClient() directly.  It's there by default.

For a unit test, like the kind of test you'd write to make sure your serialiser is working properly, you don't need or want to be poking around with a WSGIRequest object.  Instead, Django supplies a RequestFactory for just this case:

```
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory

class MyUnitTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_my_serialiser(self):
        serializer = ConferenceSerializer(
            conference,
            context={"request": RequestFactory().get("/")}
        )
        self.assertEqual(
            serialiser.data["some-key-you-expect"],
            "Some value you expect"
        )
```